# Correct Description of "class"

Tags: c#, class, typeof

```
public class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Test test = new Test();
    Console.WriteLine(test.GetType()); // -> it´s Test, of course
    int a = 5;
    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}

public class Test
{
  public string Name;
}
```

In the above case
the Type of "test" is Test, right?
And in this case the Type of "a" is int, named primitive data type,
public is an access modifier

**So my Question now is, what is class then? A keyword? A primitive Datatype? Neither, Nor?**

Please, don't explain my, what a class is doing or what's the difference between class or object, I know a class is like a construction plan.

Comment: The documentation is a good start https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes

Comment: So, as i thought, there is no official term for a class :|. Its just Keyword.

Comment: yep, a keyword telling the compiler that the following code is what you call a "construction plan".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class is a keyword that signifies to the C# compiler that a class is being declared. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/

Comment: Hey, thank you, i know its a silly question, and as i thought its just a "keyword".

Comment: @Trace No questions are silly ;)